# django: signin form is not valid

Tags: django

I'm trying to define a signin function to signin my user, but when clicking the button "Ingresar" (Signin in spanish) nothing happens.

I've tried to debug this and in my function `def signinView(request):` I've notice that Django never reaches the condition `if form.is_valid():`, so apparently my form isn't valid. I don't know why?

*It never prints "Hola3", only "Hola" and "Hola2".

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Category, Product
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout


def signinView(request):
    print("Hola")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Hola2")
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Hola3")
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            print(username)
            print(password)
            user = authenticate(username = username,
                                password = password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('shop:allProdCat')
            else:
                return redirect('signup')

    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signin.html', {'form':form})
```

**html**:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 bg-light">
                <div>
                    <br>
                    <h2 class="my_title">
                        Solo usuarios registrados
                    </h2>
                    <form method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <p>{{ form | crispy }}</p>
                        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-secondary">Ingresar</button>
                    </form>
                    <br>
                </div>

            </div>
```

**urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls')),
    path('order/', include('order.urls')),
    path('account/create/', views.signupView, name = 'signup'),
    path('account/login/', views.signinView, name = 'signin'),
    path('account/logout/', views.signoutView, name = 'signout')
]
```

Comment: post the form code and also which url are you using for this one, as i can see there are 3 urls for which the same view is being userd

Comment: @Exprator only 1 url use the singinView, the other 2 are singup and signout.  b) the html code for the form is posted, are you refering to something else?

Comment: AuthenticationForm this form code. can you post it

Comment: That one comes from: from `django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chenge this line in your view

```
form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
```

to

```
form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
```

Comment: So, apparently you need to be explicit about the data argument of the AuthenticationForm. I'd appreciate if you post the code of that function to see the arguments ir requires.

Comment: you can see the django code, of your local machine from where you are importing the form

Comment: I can see the code, but I don't know why it's necessary to explicit declare the data argument with the request post, and why it didn't work the way I did it in the first place.

Comment: that is something i cant say, because AuthenticationForm was made like that to accept the key word argument

Comment: How do you know that? I don't see anywhere in the documentation that mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Omar, why not just use the built-in authentication views rather than write your own:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
               path('account/login/', auth_views.login, name = 'login'),

]

#settings
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'url to redirect user to after successful authentication'
```

Then you just need the template and you're all set. This way keeps it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of accessing via `request.POST`, you should take it from form's `cleaned_data`:

```
def signinView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username = username,
                                password = password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('shop:allProdCat')
            else:
                return redirect('signup')
```

Also make sure if the user is `active` or registered properly to the system(via adminsite). Also please make sure if you are using a [custom backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends) instead of **modelbackend**, then the parameters for authentication could be different.

Comment: it doesn't matter if I take from `cleaned_data` or via `request.POST. The important part is to make explicit the argument `data` in `AuthenticationForm(data = request.POST)`. But I'm not sure wahy.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
return redirect('signup')
```

To

```
import django.urls import reverse
return redirect(reverse(‘signup'))
```

And all of these type of redirect functions convert into this one